# PHP mysql query is executing twice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have this PHP script:

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET motivation = motivation-10 
    WHERE id = ?
");

$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
```

But it is subtracting 20 instead of ten. When I run the query in mysql it only subtracts ten.  Why?

Comment: More input please, I doubt you only have this on your PHP? page since there are not PHP tags as well as `$dbc` is never initialized etc. so a little more context would be nice. How do you call the script etc.

Comment: You must have more than this, since this code doesn't setup the PDO object or connection...

Comment: Yes I have that but that is all in one require? with nothing else in it?

Comment: Your script is running twice, even if you only call it once. Look in your web log, and you'll probably see two requests for each page load. Maybe a rewrite rule is causing it.

Comment: I had a very similar problem to this once and after a load of shouting at my computer it turned out that I had left the `src` attribute of an image tag empty, and it was causing the PHP page to be called twice on every page load.

Comment: @DaveRandom I would never have thought of that.

Comment: @Michael It took me a very long time to figure it out, I only found it at all after accidentally commenting out too much HTML including that image, then the penny dropped.

Comment: @DaveRandom I believe that if it was duplicate calls to the same page cgwebprojects would have easily figure it out by adding a simple debug printing, no ?

Comment: @DaveRandom Wow, you are my hero! I was having a similar problem and it was an empty `href` in my favicon link. A million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your $q -> execute method is doing something silly! Check it or

May be its in a loop or

You have multiple request for this same!

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared statement looks fine. It should deduct 10 from the current value in the motivation column.

If 20 is being deducted, you're most likely calling it twice.

Ensure that you're only calling `execute()` once and if you're calling this from a web page, ensure you're not hitting it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring when you are writing PHP code and html code in the same page.. If you are clicking submit button insert first time, then again the page will refresh.. is it? Then do again executing the code.. the fix is you want to check a condition before executing statement that form gives us the data.

```
if($_POST['txtlocation']!='')
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO location(description) VALUES (:location)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $_POST['txtlocation'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
}
```